# How can I check several IDs in the same query?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I am trying to make a query of multiple IDs to the database in the same table.

The idea is to select different IDs and send them to the controller and that this answer me all the data of the IDs that I have sent.

What I send to the controller

```
[
    {
        "id": 22
    },
    {
        "id": 23
    },
    {
        "id": 11
    }
]
```

The answer that returns me

"JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of co.gov.risaralda.siete.rest.entity.Rol out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of co.gov.risaralda.siete.rest.entity.Rol out of START_ARRAY token\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]"

Controller:

```
@PostMapping ("/public/various")
     public List<Rol> listById(@Valid @RequestBody Role role) {
         Object id = role.getId ();
         return rolRepository.findById((Long) id);
     }
```

I know I am not doing well, I would appreciate an example of how I can implement this. Thank you

The desired response is:

```
[
{
   "id": 22,
   "name": "ROLE_USER",
   "created_date": "2019-10-04",
   "modified_date": "2019-10-18"
},
{
   "id": 23,
   "name": "ROLE_ADMIN",
   "created_date": "2019-10-04",
   "modified_date": "2019-10-18"
},
{
   "id": 11,
   "name": "ROLE_LECTURA",
   "created_date": "2019-10-04",
   "modified_date": "2019-10-18"
}
]
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface RolRepository extends JpaRepository <Role, Serializable> {
     public abstract List <Rol> findById (Long id);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JpaRepository.findAllById(Iterable ids)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#findAllById-java.lang.Iterable-)

> Returns all instances of the type T with the given IDs.
>   If some or all ids are not found, no entities are returned for these IDs.
>
> Note that the order of elements in the result is not guaranteed.

**Edit**:
If you want to send `ids` in the body(also you can send as `request param`) then create a `class wrapper` request for the `ids` list, example with `EmployeeIdsRequest`:

```java
@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @PostMapping
    public List<Employee> getEmployees(@RequestBody EmployeeIdsRequest idsRequest) {
        return employeeRepository.findAllById(idsRequest.getIds());
    }

    static class EmployeeIdsRequest {

        private List<Integer> ids;

        public List<Integer> getIds() {
            return ids;
        }

    }

}
```

send a request with the `body`:

```
{
  "ids": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ]
}
```

some `body` result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "DHONI"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "KHOLI"
    }
]
```

Comment: What would be the correct way to send the query? 

[
    {
        "id": 22
    },
    {
        "id": 23
    },
    {
        "id": 11
    }
]

sending this body throws me the same error .. but if I send a single id there if it returns the values to me.

repository

public List<Rol> findById(Iterable<Long> ids);

I would like to see a functional example

Comment: @AndersonMartinez added `functional example` in the answer

Comment: @AndersonMartinez also you can create any `request` class with any, for  [ { "id": 22 }, { "id": 23 }, { "id": 11 } ]  you have to create wrapper that contains single integer fields, and receive body as list in request, then via stream collect each single id(integer)  to list ids, and then pass to the repository, from my side it's complex way, BTW up to you

Comment: I'm going to try and comment

Comment: thanks for putting the example .. you have helped me a lot